# Pinterest pinit button is not getting count

Tags: pinterest

I have added a pinit button, but it is not getting the count.

```
<a data-pin-config="beside" always-show-count="true" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" /></a>
<script src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Check errors in browser's console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you did this on purpose, but just to be sure:

Your `href=//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/` link is missing the `?url=http://your_url_here` portion. How would pinterest know what page you want to link to (and get the count for)?

Check out the pinit generator on this page: http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_pin_it_button

The correct version looks more like this:

```
<a data-pin-config="beside" 
  href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fkentbrew%2F6851755809%2F&media=http%3A%2F%2Ft1.gstatic.com%2Fimages%3Fq%3Dtbn%3AANd9GcS6QBH2vJzx6BnYN_CACYuThsx4jL6MILcVHfFg6n-CX3CD5rq7ow&description=Next%20stop%3A%20Pinterest" 
  data-pin-do="buttonPin" >
    <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" />
</a>
```

If I leave out the ?url en ?media variables my pin'it! button doesn't work either :).